# Theoremstyle : adding dots

Tags: formatting, theorems, punctuation

I need an extra dot in the format of `\theoremstyle`, for example;

2.1.3. Theorem

2.1. Lemma

I use :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\swapnumbers
\newlength{\spacelength}
\settowidth{\spacelength}{\normalfont\ }
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{\itshape}{}{}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\newline}
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ #3}}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
  A lemma
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Do you use any theorem formatting packages such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem`?

Comment: I use amsthm formatting package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just comment the line

```
\swapnumbers
```

and use

```
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{\itshape}{}{}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\newline}
  {\thmnumber{#2}.\thmname{ #1}\thmnote{ #3}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%\swapnumbers
\newlength{\spacelength}
\settowidth{\spacelength}{\normalfont\ }
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{\itshape}{}{}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}{\newline}
  {\thmnumber{#2}.\thmname{ #1}\thmnote{ #3}}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
  A lemma
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: but it didn't give the result i want with \swapnumbers?

Comment: @noname What do you need it for?

Comment: I'm writing a thesis but it has an odd style, thanks...